# How do I find the average of a set of 5 scores that are taken from an XML document?

Tags: c#, xml

Right now it simply displays each score with a delay. I want to know how exactly I can take those same grades and find the average of them all, displaying it at the bottom of the page.
I'm not sure how to articulate this issue any further but I will certainly answer any question pertaining to this.

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace XML_Project1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int totalC = 0;
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            string XMLpath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\grades.xml";
            xmlDoc.Load(XMLpath);
            XmlNodeList Clist = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("grade");
            totalC = Clist.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < Clist.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Clist[i].InnerText.ToString());
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
            Console.WriteLine(totalC.ToString() + " people in XML file.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the XML file I am drawing information from.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<class>
    <student>
        <name>Sam</name>
        <grade>76</grade>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>Joe</name>
        <grade>80</grade>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>Linda</name>
        <grade>82</grade>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>Eugene</name>
        <grade>90</grade>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>Tina</name>
        <grade>92</grade>
    </student>
</class>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it seem logical to convert the value to a number, adding it to a variable each time to accumulate them, and then divide that accumulated value by the count of the values you added? IOW, how would you do this using paper and a pencil?

Comment: Try to use the newer `XDocument` classes rather than the old `XmlDocument` ones. It's LINQ-to-XML that you want to use now.

Comment: Calling `.InnerText.ToString()` isn't necessary as `.InnerText` would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
string XMLpath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\grades.xml";
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(XMLpath);

IEnumerable<XElement> gradeElements = xmlDoc.Root.Descendants("grade");

int totalC = gradeElements.Count();
double averageGrade = gradeElements.Select(x => (double)x).Average();

Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
Console.WriteLine($"{totalC} people in XML file.");
Console.WriteLine($"{averageGrade} average grade.");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: This worked very well, thank you. I'd never seen "IEnumerable" before as I am still very new but I think I know how it works. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using xml linq and putting results into a dictionary

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, int> dict = doc.Descendants("student")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("name"), y => (int)y.Element("grade"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            decimal average = (decimal)dict.Average(x => x.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could begin by converting each element to an Int, rather than storing it as collection of XmlNode. For example,

```
var Clist = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("grade")
                  .Cast<XmlNode>()
                  .Select(x=> Convert.ToInt32(x.InnerText))
                  .ToList();
```

Now you could calculate the Number of Items(peopl) and Average as

```
totalC = Clist.Count;
var average = Clist.Average();
```

Complete code

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
string XMLpath = @"e:\data.xml";
xmlDoc.Load(XMLpath);
var Clist = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("grade")
                  .Cast<XmlNode>()
                  .Select(x=> Convert.ToInt32(x.InnerText))
                  .ToList();

var totalC = Clist.Count;
var average = Clist.Average();
for (int i = 0; i < Clist.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Clist[i]);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

}
Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
Console.WriteLine($"{totalC} people in XML file.");
Console.WriteLine($"Average {average}");
```

Please include `System.Linq` namespace